# Do we need three cloudbuild.yml files for a simple setup in Google Cloud Container Builder?

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, google-container-registry, google-cloud-repository

On Google Cloud Container Builder we want to:

- Push any branch to REPO:BRANCH
- Push any tag to REPO:TAG
- Push master to REPO:latest

Do we need a separate `cloudbuild.yml` file for each? Is there a lighter way of doing this?

We need to use a file rather than a trigger in the UI, because the build takes 20 minutes, and the timeout of the UI triggers are 10 minutes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At this time, using three different config files for the different naming schemes is the best solution.

Letting you use a single config file for all the ways you want to build (different triggers on the same repo, or from `gcloud` directly, etc) is one of our goals, so we'll take your use-case into consideration.

Comment: OK. Even if it's "TAG_OR_BRANCH_NAME" then that'd cut out a lot of duplication

Comment: You could use "gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/foo:${TAG_NAME}${BRANCH_NAME}" right now and get either the tag or branch name (only one will ever be set), but this does not help you turn master into :latest.